# Does queries with multiple equality filters and no range/orderby filters enhanced by using Composite Index in cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The indexing policy [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy) explains the composite index is useful when there is minimum of one equality and one range/orderby query. But it doesn't explain if it's useful when the query have only multiple equality filters and no range/order by filter.

The Mongo DB has a equivalent [compound](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing) index that helps while querying with multiple equality filter and no range filter.

For example the query will be like this.

Select * from c where c.FirstName = "Hi" and c.LastName ="Hello"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the precise query you have as an example it is unlikely to help. It could provide some benefit but you'd have to have data with extreme cardinality such as a time stamp.